# How does this "days in month" function work?

Tags: javascript

```
  function GetDaysInMonth(month, year) 
  {
      return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
  }
```

Ok, I don't see what this is doing specifically, this part:

```
 new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
```

I know what `getDate()` does, but then I looked up `Date` in JavaScript but in this particular example, I don't see why you'd pass 32 here. How can this be returning the number of days in whatever month and year you're passing to it?

Comment: actually it's returning 31 for february so the fing thing doesn't even work.  I'm just pissed because my boss just tells me how to reduce 30 lines of code but then the fing function he tells me to use doesn't even work!  Not that I can't fix it but you know how conceded asswipes are about code reviews sometimes.

Comment: I should have just looked up this method, it was stolen: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2099

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "32nd day" of any month will roll over to the next one. If there are 31 days in a month, the "32nd day" will be the 1st of the next month. If there are 30, the "32nd day" will be the 2nd of the next month. If there are 28, the "32nd day" will be the 4th of the next month.

Subtract any of these from 32 and you get the correct number.

Comment: so lets say I pass in Feb for 2009.  Ok, then passing in 32 should give me 4 with that GetDate().  And then you take 32-4...is that correct?  Ok why then do I get 31 back still for Feb

Comment: 32 - new Date(2009,1,32).getDate()
returns
28
for me. Remember, months are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.prototype.monthDays: function(){
 var d= new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth()+1, 0);
 return d.getDate();
}
```

The **zero** date of next month is the last date of this month...

**alert(new Date().monthDays())**//  any date object

Comment: Browser-dependent results.  Not so good in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function GetDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    return (new Date(new Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)-86400000)).getDate();
}
```

This is using the first day of the preceeding month and substracts one day (86400000 milloseconds) from it to get the last day of the given month. Note that the `Date`’s *month* parameter expects values from 0 (January) to 11 (December). But for `GetDaysInMonth` use 1 (January) to 12 (December):

```
GetDaysInMonth(12, 2007) // returns 31
GetDaysInMonth(1, 2008) // returns 31
GetDaysInMonth(2, 2008) // returns 29
```

If you want to use the same values as for `Date`, use `new Date(year, month+1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` instead.

Comment: I don't get yours, what's all the 1,0,0,... and the -864000

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date